# Question about the proof that a finite integral domain is a field

Tags: integration, group-theory, finite-fields

Typical proof for this goes somewhat like this

> Consider a, $a^2$, $a^3$ etc. Since there are only finitely many
> elements we must have $a^m = a^n$ for some m < n.

I understand that because it's finite group at some point $a^n$ will not keep increasing but will go lower. But I don't get why $a^m$ has to equal to $a^n$.

Can't $a^m = b$ where b < $a^m$ but is a different element which is not a power of `a`. Won't this still satisfy the condition of finiteness of the group?

Comment: Here you are *only* looking at powers of $a$. As you keep producing them: $a, a^2,a^3\ldots$, *at some point they will repeat*. This is because the whole integral domain is finite, let's say with $k$ elements, then at least two of $a, a^2, a^3,\ldots,a^k,a^{k+1}$ will be the same. (Pigeonhole principle!) Now, let $a^m=a^n$ with $m\ne n$ is one (say, the first) instance of this repetition. Does this help?

Comment: @StinkingBishop I understand why a^n can't be infinite & it has go to a lower element at some point because of the pigeonhole principle. However, why does that lower element have to be a power of a. Why can't it be a different element of the Group which is not a power of a.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "lower element". If you mean "the element of the form $a^m$ for a lower $m$" then you have already answered your question, because that element is presumed to be a power of $a$. If you mean something else, could you please explain?

Comment: @StinkingBishop - why should it be a power of a?

Comment: Because you are only looking at powers of $a$. You are *only* looking at $a, a^2, a^3$ etc. Two of those values must eventually be equal to each other, and they are *all* powers of $a$. I mean, if the set of *all* elements of the integral domain is finite, then of course the set of all *powers of $a$* is finite too, and potentially smaller than the former.

Comment: @StinkingBishop  - assume the largest integer which is the result of a power of a is X. And a^m = X. Why should a^(m+1) be equal to one of a^0 to a^(m-1). Why can't it be another element of the group which is not equal to one of the earlier powers?

Comment: Wait a minute... Largest *integer*? We are not talking about integers in the first place. We are talking about an *integral domain*, which is, as we know, a commutative ring without zero divisors. Additionally, it is finite, so this integral domain is definitely not $\mathbb Z$. Maybe that is what is confusing you?

Comment: @StinkingBishop - no, I was just giving an example of an integral domain with integers as the members of the integral domain. Not talking about Z.

Comment: The finiteness of the domain means that $a^m=a^n$ for some pair of integers $m\neq n$. Then we either have $m<n$ or $m>n$. One is larger than the other. It makes no difference to the argument which way it is. Just switch the roles of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen -`The finiteness of the domain means that am=an for some pair of integers m≠n` - got it now.

Comment: Glad to hear that!